# Demonstrate buffer overflow in C in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: c, gcc, ubuntu-13.04

As part of my assignment i have to demonstrate stackoverflow in my linux box.

My Box Config:
OS: Ubuntu 13.04

GCC version: 4.6.3

I tried to compile the program with the flag -fno-stack-protector, the program complies successfully but Segmentation fault error shows up when i trigger stack overflow. How can i show the actual o/p.
Buffer Over Flow Pgm:

```
int main(int argc, char**argv)
 {
   int authentication=0;
   char cUsername[10], cPassword[10];
   strcpy(cUsername, argv[1]);
   strcpy(cPassword, argv[2]);
   if(strcmp(cUsername, "admin") == 0 && strcmp(cPassword, "adminpass") == 0)
{
       authentication = 1;}
if(authentication)
{
       printf("Access granted");} 
else
{
       printf("Wrong username and password");
    }return 0;}
```

If i give an IP like AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA A
then it should show Acess granted but right now it shows segmentation fault

Comment: You want to overflow the stack and execute shell code?

Comment: Yes i want to copy a long string into a small char array.

Comment: That sounds more like stack corruption than stack overflow.

Comment: Okie.....So how can i successfully demonstrate it..?

Comment: If you're having a SIGSEGV then you already demonstrated it: you wrote too much data in a small buffer, you were thrown a segment violation by the OS. What do you want to demonstrate exactly?

Comment: Try an infinite recursion such as `void foo() {foo();}`. This will give you a stack overflow.

Comment: Or `void kaboom (void) { volatile uint8_t waste_of_space[1000]={0}; kaboom(); }`

Comment: I have added the code of my pgm...

Answer (score 2):

This is what happens with my c compiler if you launch the program with these arguments: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA B :

```
int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
  int authentication=0;
  char cUsername[10], cPassword[10];

  strcpy(cUsername, argv[1]);
  // now cUsername contains "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"
  // and authentication contains "0x41414141" because it has been overwritten because of the
  // buffer overflow of cUsername

  strcpy(cPassword, argv[2]);
  //now cPassword contains "B"

  if(strcmp(cUsername, "admin") == 0 && strcmp(cPassword, "adminpass") == 0)
  {
    // strings are different so we don't get here
    authentication = 1;
  }

  if (authentication)
  {
    // authentication still contains 0x41414141 therefore we get here
    printf("Access granted");
  } 
  else
  {
    printf("Wrong username and password");
  }

  // here we will get a segmentation fault, because the return adress which is on the
  // stack will have been overwritten with 0x41414141 which is most probably an
  // invalid address
  return 0;
}
```

BTW if you format your code correctly it is much easier to read.

**Important**

Depending on your system, "Access granted" might not get printed out because if the output is buffered, the output buffer normally gets emptied **after** the return from the main function and since the program seg faults before, the output buffer is never emptied and the message is never displayed. Try to add a \n at the end of the "Access granted\n" string.

Comment: Could always flush the output buffer with `fflush(stdout);`

Comment: So i wan to get the message Access granted when that o/p comes but it goes diectly to segmentation fault

Comment: Run your program with a debugger and you will see exactly where the seg fault occurs.